# How to do reverse split

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have two variables (values), in this two values I want to take:

1. `countryName`
2. `stateName`
3. `cityName`
4. `localityName`
5. `sublocalityName`

So I am using `split()` but it is not working properly, First string is working fine but second string is not working properly, I think reverse wise we have split the string, and we have to tale all those values, but I don't know how to do?

```js
var address = "8th Main Rd, Marathahalli Village, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India";

var resAddress = address.split(",");
var sublocalityNameTrim = resAddress[1];
var sublocalityName = sublocalityNameTrim.trim();
var localityNameTrim = resAddress[2];
var localityName = localityNameTrim.trim();
var cityNameTrim = resAddress[3];
var cityName = cityNameTrim.trim();
var stateAndPincode = resAddress[4];
var countryTrim = resAddress[5];
var countryName = countryTrim.trim();
var sc = stateAndPincode.trim();
var stateAndPincodeSplid = sc.split(" ");
var stateNameTrim = stateAndPincodeSplid[0];
var stateName = stateNameTrim.trim();
var pincode = stateAndPincodeSplid[1];

console.log("countryName = " + countryName);
console.log("stateName = " + stateName);
console.log("cityName = " + cityName);
console.log("localityName = " + localityName);
console.log("sublocalityName = " + sublocalityName);


var address1 = "846, 2nd Main Rd, AECS Layout - D Block, AECS Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India";

var resAddress1 = address1.split(",");
var sublocalityNameTrim = resAddress1[1];
var sublocalityName = sublocalityNameTrim.trim();
var localityNameTrim = resAddress1[2];
var localityName = localityNameTrim.trim();
var cityNameTrim = resAddress1[3];
var cityName = cityNameTrim.trim();
var stateAndPincode = resAddress1[4];
var countryTrim = resAddress1[5];
var countryName = countryTrim.trim();
var sc = stateAndPincode.trim();
var stateAndPincodeSplid = sc.split(" ");
var stateNameTrim = stateAndPincodeSplid[0];
var stateName = stateNameTrim.trim();
var pincode = stateAndPincodeSplid[1];

console.log("countryName = " + countryName);
console.log("stateName = " + stateName);
console.log("cityName = " + cityName);
console.log("localityName = " + localityName);
console.log("sublocalityName = " + sublocalityName);
```

Comment: The issue is because the `,` in the first line of the second address is throwing out the indexes in your split array. To fix this I'd suggest wrapping each value in quotes, eg. `'"846, 2nd Main Rd","AECS Layout - D Block","AECS Layout",...` then using a CSV parser to read the values.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan, Can you update your answer on snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a working solution below. I have used Object instead of individual variables. You can extract the properties and assign to variables as per your need.

```js
var address1 = "8th Main Rd, Marathahalli Village, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India";

var address2 = "846, 2nd Main Rd, AECS Layout - D Block, AECS Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India"

function getAddObj(add) {
  var addArray = add.split(',').reverse().map(function(item) {
    return item.trim()
  })
  return addArray.reduce(function(acc, item, index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        acc.country = item;
        return acc;
      case 1:
        acc.state = item.split(' ')[0]
        return acc;
      case 2:
        acc.city = item;
        return acc;
      case 3:
        acc.locality = item;
        return acc;
      case 4:
        acc.subLocality = item;
        return acc;
      default:
        return acc;
    }
  }, {});
}

var countryName = getAddObj(address1).country;
var stateName = getAddObj(address1).state;

console.log(countryName);
console.log(stateName);
```

Comment: Now i want to take only countryName and stateName means how we can take can you please update your answer

Comment: Thanks,i got the exact answer

Answer (score 0):

```
        var address = "8th Main Rd, Marathahalli Village, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India";

        var resAddress = address.split(",");


        console.log("countryName = " + resAddress[resAddress.length - 1].trim());
        console.log("stateName = " + resAddress[resAddress.length - 2].trim());
        console.log("cityName = " + resAddress[resAddress.length - 3].trim());
        console.log("localityName = " + resAddress[resAddress.length - 4].trim());
        console.log("sublocalityName = " + resAddress[resAddress.length - 5].trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var address1 = "8th Main Rd, Marathahalli Village, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India";
var address2 = "846, 2nd Main Rd, AECS Layout - D Block, AECS Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India"

function printObj(add) {
    var resAddress = add.split(',').reverse()
    console.log("countryName = " + resAddress[0].trim());
    console.log("stateName = " + resAddress[1].trim());
    console.log("cityName = " + resAddress[2].trim());
    console.log("localityName = " + resAddress[3].trim());
    console.log("sublocalityName = " + findSubLocality(resAddress));
}

function findSubLocality(data) {
    var subLocality = "";
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 4; i--) {
        subLocality = subLocality + data[i] + ",";
    }
    subLocality = subLocality.substr(0, subLocality.length - 1);
    return subLocality;
}

printObj(address1);
printObj(address2);
```